# Low performance ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I am performance testing my piece of code working on activeMQ,

I use `virtual topics` in there. when I send about a 1000 Concurrent requests to en-queue my messages,it takes ages to en-queue all the messages, and sometimes it just hangs in between and starts back after sometime.

I am using JDBC message store,I know some performance effect might be because of that.

Is this hit on performance mainly due to virtual topics?,because on activemq Website they Specify a very high performance of the topic(under ideal conditions ofcourse)

P.S: 1 message takes almost 13-15 milliseconds to be enqueued and dequeued, which is way too high than what performance activeMQ claims to have

- http://activemq.apache.org/performance.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance hit is mainly because of the JDBC message store. Virtual Topics do not differ much in performance compared to durable subscriptions.

Please use LevelDB or KahaDB if you want performance. The JDBC store is mainly there for compability with setups that already uses fail-over secured databases with backups etc and want to use them for messages as well. You won't come even close to the numbers in the performance page with plain JDBC.